# Gerar relatório SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

```
Select Count(id_cand), count(b.Carg) As Carg, Count(Vags), id_cand / Carg 
From Insc as a 
inner join Carg as b
on a.CodigoCarg = b.CodigoCarg
Group by a.id_cand, b.Carg, vags
```

Comment: Olá, seu código foi formatado para uma melhor aparência. Caso queira, é possível editar a postagem. Para isso basta clicar no botão [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/527597/edit). Também removi mensagens de cumprimentos [saiba o motivo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/38/como-se-portar-ao-perguntar-responder).

Comment: Qual seria o agrupamento correto, se não este indicado no seu `group by`?

Comment: Na realidade o Group by está correto, o caso é que o count nesse caso não funcionou pq não contou as linhas, e preciso totalizar a quantidade de inscritos e quando escrevo o código abaixo só aparece 1 e tem mais candidatos, fora que ainda tenho que dividir a coluna Numero inscritos com o total de vagas .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*sem teste todavia */
Select Count(CodigoCandidato) As Numero_de_inscritos, 
       count(b.DescricaoCargo) As Cargo, 
       Count(Vagas), 
       (CASE WHEN Count(Vagas) <> 0 
             THEN (Count(CodigoCandidato)/Count(Vagas))
             ELSE NULL END) As Demanda_candidatos_por_vagas
From Inscricao as a 
inner join Cargo as b
on a.CodigoCargo = b.CodigoCargo
```

Comment: muito obrigado, ajudou bastante!!